# I want to check open applications before turn off my computer through java program

Tags: java, windows, application-shutdown, system-shutdown

Actually I am working on a java based application which has a functionality to turn off my system on a specific time and it's working fine but, the requirement says that if any application is open then it should not be close before turn off my system must have to close all the open application manually.
I am unable to find out the solution.

Comment: This will be hard: how do you know what constitutes an "application" and what constitutes a system process? And even if you can identify them, how will you close them any differently to the OS closing them as it shuts down?

Comment: @Richard: well, Windows **can** distinguish them, so probably it can be done programatically as well, especially with help of some external tool. And subodh wants states, that such apps should be closed **manually**. It sounds perfectly doable, even if it requires some native solution.

Comment: @sudobh: Have you considered the possibility that Java is not the right tool for this job?  What other tools have you objectively evaluated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried this but it looks like you would have to use: Runtime.getRuntime().exec().  [This](http://www.ke-cai.net/2010/12/find-and-kill-running-windows-processes.html) seems to be a pretty good example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Java JNI 
https://github.com/twall/jna/

Get the list of all processes via WinAPI and check for user_name in PEB of a process. 
Or this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390460(v=vs.85).aspx :)